# How to check if user has already downloaded non-consumable item Inapp purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am providing non-consumable item in my application.

**suppose user purchases that item and tries to install that application on another device with same id** . If the user is logged in and already have purchased that item , i want to show some pop up and tell user that you have already purchased it so download it for free now.what happens right now is , when i click to purchase item again then is says that u have already purchased that item click to download.

Is there any way to get user login details and check if user has already made In-app purchase or not.

**there is a problem when i login and try to buy already purchased item . two kinds of alert view appears time to time** . i am using sandbox environment.

1. **you've already purchased** this but it hasn't been downloaded.Tap OK to download it now.
   this alert view has only OK button .when we press Ok  control goes to - (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
2. you've already purchased this.Tap OK to download it again for free.this alert view has two button one is Cancel and another is OK . On pressing OK button control goes to - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction which is fine.

An idea why transaction is showing this peculiar behavior .

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you think you need to do anything different.

As you said, the system detects that the user already owns the product, and gives the user a “click to download” alert.  If the user chooses to download, then you get an `SKPaymentTransaction` whose state is either “purchased” or “restored” (I forget which).  Then you just provide the product as usual.  So the user knows that he's not being charged a second time, and he gets the product.

If you're saying you want to automatically detect what products the user owns, without the user having to do anything: you can only do that by sending `restoreCompletedTransactions` to the `SKPaymentQueue`.  When you do that, the user may have to enter his iTunes password.  I prefer to just have a “restore purchases” button in my UI, so the user knows why he's being asked for his password.

Comment: i have edited my question . now other problem has come .can you help me out

Comment: do u have any idea ? Why this different behaviour on different occasion in sandbox environment ?

Comment: I have no idea.  I haven't seen that problem.

Comment: when i click buy button , i want to cancel transaction after a timeout .. so can you tell me how to cancel the transaction

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be lots of stability issues with the Sandbox, see this thread https://devforums.apple.com/thread/164500?tstart=0 in the Apple Developer Forum (login necessary). I have been testing an in app purchase with a consumable and never seen case 2, I get only case 1 (just as mentioned in the forum). So you might consider yourself lucky to even get 2) from time to time :(

Answer (score 0):

Having faced both problem, I have following thoughts on them

1] Many developers, including me, solved first problem by restarting the device.

2] For second problem , as the "purchased" or "restored" callbacks are called on taping "OK" so the product will be available, by itself.

Hope it helps !